# servicestack.text formatted indented json

Tags: servicestack

Is it possible to get the servicestack.text to produce formatted/indented json?

I was wanting it to write the json to a text file.  it would be nice if it was already formatted nicely.

Comment: found this simple json formatter http://www.limilabs.com/blog/json-net-formatter

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the [.Dump()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/c9ae1446f883ed609abcffc0812e4706b3a30a1e/src/ServiceStack.Text/TypeSerializer.cs#L200) extension method.  Should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah, it appears to be a pretty print of the JSV format.  Here's a suggestion from the author to get true JSON formatting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13757113/684428

Answer (score 1):

Update from 2017, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13757113/):

> The new `string.IndentJson()` extension method available from v4.5.5 will let you pretty-print JSON otherwise you can install a Pretty JSONView extension for Chrome or Firefox to see pretty JSON or you can paste the JSON in [jsonprettyprint.com](http://jsonprettyprint.com/)